# Creating a 'frame' that hides all but what it contains in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, crop, viewport

I just started with pyGame and I would like to create a frame that crops whatever I display on screen.
i.e. independently of what my world contains, this frame should cover everything but what it contains.

Think about it as the frame used to crop images on the iphone (see picture below). Eventually I want to make the frame interactive, so that I can move it around or change its size, but for the time being a static frame would do.
And I have no idea where to start from.. any help is appreciated!

[[image: example of cropping frame[1]]

Comment: Pygame is not a good library for UI-type interfaces, take a look at [tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) or ttk.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a GUI. I'm trying to find a way to 'crop' my viewport in a 3D world created via pygame.
I'm using the word 'frame' as a frame around a painting, i.e. something that surrounds the 3D content that I want to show.

Comment: Ah, In this case maybe just create a large black rect and on top create a different rect and then play around with the viewport placing. Im not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this; one way is to draw a black `Surface` on the entire screen, but have a "hole" in that black `Surface`.

An easy way to create that "hole" is to simply draw a rectangle with the right `colorkey`. What is the [`colorkey`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)?

> When blitting this Surface onto a destination, any pixels that have the same color as the colorkey will be transparent

Sounds useful, so let's give it a try:

```
import random
import pygame as pg

IMAGE = pg.Surface((50, 50), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(IMAGE, (240, 120, 0), [(0, 50), (25, 0), (50, 50)])

class Actor(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, grp, bounds, pos):
        self._layer = 0
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, grp)
        self.image = IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vec = pg.math.Vector2()
        # just a random directon for movement
        self.vec.from_polar((10, random.randrange(0, 360)))
        self.bounds = bounds

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(*self.vec)
        # try staying on screen
        if not self.bounds.contains(self.rect):
            self.vec.from_polar((10, random.randrange(0, 360)))

class Cursor(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, grp, bounds):
        self._layer = 1000
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, grp)
        self.image = pg.Surface((bounds.width, bounds.height))
        self.image.set_colorkey(pg.Color('yellow'))
        # we start with the entire screen black
        # if the screen should be fully visible at the start, we could use yellow instead
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('black'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # here we store the position of the mouse when we start drawing the hole
        self.start = None
        # here we store the entire rect of the hole so we can later move it around
        self.inner_rect = None

    def mousedown(self):
        self.start = pg.mouse.get_pos()

    def mouseup(self):
        self.start = None

    def move(self, rel):
        self.inner_rect.move_ip(rel)
        self.recreate()

    def update(self):
        if not self.start:
            return
        pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        p = pos[0] - self.start[0], pos[1] - self.start[1]
        self.inner_rect = pg.Rect(self.start, p)
        self.recreate()

    def recreate(self):
        # here we update our hole
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('black'))
        pg.draw.rect(self.image, pg.Color('yellow'), self.inner_rect)
        pg.draw.rect(self.image, pg.Color('white'), self.inner_rect, 2)

def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    cursor = Cursor(all_sprites, screen.get_rect())
    for _ in range(20):
        Actor(all_sprites, screen.get_rect(), (random.randrange(600), random.randrange(440)))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    cursor.mousedown()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:
                    cursor.mouseup()    
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
                    cursor.move(event.rel)

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill(pg.Color('darkblue'))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

[image]

Use the left mouse button to start drawing your frame, and use the right mouse button to move it.

As you can see, we have a black `Surface` with yellow as colorkey. When we want to make a part of the screen visible, we draw a yellow rectangle, which in turn will be transparent, making the scene underneath it visible.

Comment: I love this! Thanks